# Building Ghost theme but my CSS isn't linking

Tags: html, css, sass, handlebars.js

I'm so sorry if someone else has already asked this issue, but I've been searching for hours for a solution to this problem and can't seem to find an answer. I'm a budding front-end designer who is trying to learn back-end development on the fly. I'm developing a Ghost theme, piggybacking off of Casper. Right now I'm just trying to put up a super simple landing page but none of my CSS is linking. I've tried installing Handlebars, I've tried writing it in Sass with the intent to compile from the command line but it kept throwing errors. Hopefully one of you can help me because I'm pretty sure I've exhausted Google.

My HTML (saved as a .hbs)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/comingsoon.css" />
```

My file structure

```
~/git/ghost/content/themes/MissionAtWork/assets/css
```

If you need anymore info I'd be happy to provide it. Thank you so much in advance! Y'all are lifesavers!

Comment: Your HTML and File Structure seem to be pointing to different places. Maybe try something like: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ghost/content/themes/MissionAtWork/assets/css/comingsoon.css" />

Comment: Just to follow on from what Mark said, one thing to do is to open your css file directly in your browser, and then copy the url and use that as the href

Comment: Neither seem to be working. If there's an existing sass folder that has some styling, might I need to manipulate the code from there as opposed to adding in an additional css document in the compiled css folder? Might that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had to go into the sass files and edit them from there. *Not* from the css. Also my edits were actually working, but my `gulp` froze whenever I made a syntax error. Simple restart of my `gulp` window did the trick. Thank you everyone for your help!